# PHP if condition doesn't work for urls matching

Tags: php

I am trying to match two URLs but it seems doesn't work. I have tried works fine if I put manually.

Here is the code:

```
$referby = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$link1="http://domain.com/admin/ajax/passcodev.php?order_id=".$orderid;
$link2="http://www.domain.com/admin/ajax/passcodev.php?order_id=".$orderid;

if($referby<>$link1 || $referby<>$link2)
 {
    header('Location:passcodev.php?order_id='.$orderid);
 }
```

I have no idea where I am doing mistake.

Comment: <> i think it's for different... use != instead

Comment: @MarcoMura `<>` is exactly the same as `!=`

Comment: @Magicprog.fr i didn't know that comparison operator o.o thanks for your input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if($referby<>$link1 || $referby<>$link2)` means if `$referby` does not match `$link1` *or* `$link2`, proceed. Since it can't match both it *always* evaluates to true.

You need to use `&&` (and):

```
if($referby != $link1 && $referby != $link2)
```